# Parent Category and Subcategory default text generated from category name

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy-terms, wp-list-categories

I need help on something I am unable to do on my website.

I have several category and sub category on my page. For E.g

- Food

  - Apple
  - Orange
- Shirt
- Laptop

  - HP
  - Dell

I would like on each main category page and sub category page a default text appearing as so:

For sub category

```
The best Food Apple you can get.
```

For the main category

```
The best Food you can get
```

I am using the below code for the moment but the main category is still displaying the subcategory e.g FoodApple. Ideally the main category should only display The best Food you can get.

```
<h2 class="supply">The best 

   <?php
$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' );

foreach ( $terms as $term ){
    if ( $term->parent == 0 ) {
        echo $term->name ;
    }
}

foreach ( $terms as $term ){
    if ( $term->parent == !0 ) {
        echo $term->name ;
    }
}
?>  you can get </h2>
```

I would be so grateful if someone can help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your second condition is incorrect for child term. 
replace

```
foreach ( $terms as $term ){
if ( $term->parent == !0 ) {
    echo $term->name ;
}
```

}

with

```
foreach ( $terms as $term ){
if ( !$term->parent == 0 ) {
    echo $term->name ;
}
```

}

check if it is working

Comment: Still the same issue the parent category is taking the name of subcategory e.g FoodApple